# How to get the child element of a JSON string with multiple level in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, json, json.net

This is my JSON string generated by C# JSON parser:

```
{
    "NewDataSet": {
        "Table": [
            {
                "ResultId": "1",
                "AttachmentId": "1",
                "AttachmentName": "Report1",
                "RowsCount": "34",
                "NotifyUserName": "william",
                "InsBy": "developer",
                "InsAt": "2012-12-07T17:28:01.46+08:00",
                "IsNotify": "false"
            },
            {
                "ResultId": "2",
                "AttachmentId": "2",
                "AttachmentName": "Report2",
                "RowsCount": "37",
                "NotifyUserName": "william",
                "InsBy": "developer",
                "InsAt": "2012-12-07T17:28:15.57+08:00",
                "IsNotify": "false"
            },
            {
                "ResultId": "3",
                "AttachmentId": "3",
                "AttachmentName": "Report3",
                "RowsCount": "69",
                "NotifyUserName": "william",
                "InsBy": "developer",
                "InsAt": "2012-12-07T17:28:25.58+08:00",
                "IsNotify": "false"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then I would like to parse the string to front end JavaScript to iterate the value.
I did this way.

```
  var jsonText;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/MethodWithNoParameterJSON",
            data: {},
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                //rulesName = dbtitle+msg.d;
                //rulesCount = +msg.d;
                jsonText = msg.d;
               alert(jsonText.NewDataSet.Table[0].ResultId), 
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
            }
        });
```

How can I get the child element data like `jsonText.NewDataSet.Table[0].ResultId`? Whenever I call `alert(jsonText.NewDataSet.Table[0].ResultId)`, it will always prompt null or undefined object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `msg.d` to set your `jsonText` variable? Where does the `.d` property come from? The `msg` parameter should already be the object created from your JSON response. Try this instead:

```
msg.NewDataSet.Table[0].ResultId
```

(And note that your `jsonText` variable is badly named: what you have at that point is not JSON or "text", it is an object - or, in your case, `undefined` because `msg.d` is undefined. But you are trying to use it as an object, not as JSON.)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have changed msg.d to msg.NewDataSet.Table[0].ResultId but it still prompting the value as undefined.

Comment: What do you get if you add `console.log(msg)` to the beginning of the success function?

Comment: ok, but is console.log(msg) written inside success: { } . I have tried but showing console is null or undefined

Comment: The `alert()` shown in your question is inside the success function, so I assume that is where you were originally getting null or undefined object errors, so yes, add `console.log(msg)` as the first statement inside the success function and see what it says. If it doesn't show your object then there is perhaps something else going on beyond just the issue of how to access the `ResultId` property. (If you were trying to access it _outside_ the function you are probably having problems because the Ajax call is asynchronous.)

Comment: if i put console.log(msg) it still show undefined, but if i change to console.log(msg.d), it show this" LOG: {"NewDataSet":{"Table":[{"ResultId":"1","AttachmentId":"1","AttachmentName":"Report1","RowsCount":"34","NotifyUserName":"william","InsBy":"developer","InsAt":"2012-12-07T17:28:01.46+08:00","IsNotify":"false"},{"....etc

Comment: So as I asked in my answer, where does the `.d` property come from? You don't show it in the JSON in your question. If there really is a `.d` property with the value you show then your original code should've worked. Unless `.d` is a _string_ rather than an object?

Comment: hi, thanks for the feed back that you have provided. I have finally figure out the reason why it is always null, i have converted the json formatted string as object but not parse it into javascript object. Once i parse it as javascript object, then i can use obj.NewDataSet.Table[0] to call any key pair values. Anyway, without your input, i will not be able to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

typo? I think it should be

```
jsonText.NewDataSet.Table[0].ResultId // replace RulesId with ResultId
```

Comment: Hi, i just edited the original typing error. It should be what you have pointed out, but it still returning null or undefined.